# When I use projection to create a flatten ViewModel I lose metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Many tutorials say that when i have to pass data from controller to view the best way is to create a flattern viewMoldel.
This solution came to solve also other problems (like the eager loading problem).
My concern is that when i create a flatten viewModel **I lose all the informations that I store in the entities via annotation**.

Suppose that i have a model composed by

```
class product{
  [DisplayName("Name")] 
  public String Name{get;set;}

  [DisplayName("Image")] 
  public String Image{get;set;}

  [DisplayName("Description")] 
  public String Description{get;set;}

  public String CategoryId{get;set;}
}

class category{
  [DisplayName("Code")] 
  Public String Id{get;set;}

  [DisplayName("Category name")] 
  public String Name{get;set;}

}
```

To render a grid that show product informations many tutorials say that the best way is to provide a flatten viewModel like this:

```
class productGridViewModel{
  Public String ProductName{get;set}
  Public String ProductImage{get;set}
  Public String ProductDescription{get;set}
  Public String CategoryName{get;set}
}
```

My concern is that I need to write again all the DisplayName annotations in the viewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are flattening your model entities into ViewModels, shouldn't the attributes be removed from the model entity classes and placed on the ViewModels? Your model entities will not be used for display, so they should not have those attributes.

Comment: I conclude that ther is no a simple solution to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your view model is your data consumption use case. If you need metadata then the view model flattened or otherwise will need to support it. May be you need to add it dynamically? Or if that's too onerous, then you need to encode it at compile time.

Edit.

You can use T4 transformations to ensure that dependent code it kept up to date. In fact we use this allow users to customise the DB and thus allow express the customisations in the view models.

What you do is put the source of the truth in one assembly, and then use a T4 transform file to create other representations from this assembly using reflection in another assembly.

Comment: my priority is to get the smarter way to write less code and have things centralized in one place if possible. For exampe if tomonrow i change the dispalyname for a given product property I want that this change take place in all my site and I don't want to remember all the palces where i used this property and lose time to find and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to have read-only properties in the viewModel which read the meta-data of the underlying Model object. Then you can bind this meta-data with the appropriate control in the View.

As below:

```
class productGridViewModel{ 
  Public String ProductName{get;set} 
  Public String ProductImage{get;set} 
  Public String ProductDescription{get;set} 
  Public String CategoryName{get;set} 

public string ProductDisplayName
        {
            get
            {
//Please dont mind this code.. I am sure you can write it in much better way.
                return typeof(Producy).GetProperty("Name").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayName))[0].ToString();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I use a UiGridComponent that retrieve the metadata from annotations (like the HtmlHelper.LabelFor(..) ). 
So the ProductName property has no DisplayName attribute.
The UiGridComponent don't know about the ProductDisplayName.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it would be by implementing a custom AssociatedMetadataProvider. This isn't as much work as you'd think, and you could implement one to generate metadata from an xml file, database, convention, or even buddy types like the current one does.

The only thing you'd need to do differently to the current implementation is allow buddy types to contain field/properties which don't exist on the model they apply to, because that is the only thing currently preventing you from creating a buddy type which you could apply to all view/editor models of your particula model.

Its a bit of work and depends how much time it would save you but don't forget most of the MVC source code is available and you wouldn't have to change very much

Martin